# XSLT select element with two different keys

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to get an element with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pays>
    <pay id="23">
        <accounts>
            <account id="2">
                <name>Jonh</name>
            </account>
            <account id="3">
                <name>Mary</name>
            </account>
        </accounts>
    </pay>
</pays>
```

I want to get the account given key of the elements "pay" and "account".

I tried to do:

```
<xsl:key name="id_account" match="account" use="concat(@id,@id)"/>
```

But this wrong and do not know to solve this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your key like this:

```
<xsl:key name="id_account" match="account" use="concat(../../@id, '+', @id)"/>
```

And then to select an `account` element using pay id and account id, you can do this:

```
key('id_account', concat($payId, '+', $accountId))
```

(though `payId` and `accountId` don't necessarily need to be stored in variables)